# cheat avr-gcc optimization option -ffunction-sections with IRQ using

Tags: gcc, optimization, avr

I have a special avr-gcc problem without an solution up to now.

I use the gcc option "-ffunction-sections" with linking options "-Wl,--gc-sections".
This will avoid to link functions that are not used within the code.
It is working perfect with microcontrollers that have only some KByte flash.

But now i have the case that this optimization will kill code that is needed!
I will try to explain the conditions.

1. I have a timer interrupt that is doing something every 800 µs.
   After 8 times it will increment a variable "Ticks" to generate a clock.

   ```
   ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
   {
           counter ++;
           if (counter > 7) {
                   counter = 0;
                   Ticks ++;          // generating my time
           }
   }
   ```
2. Now i want to use a function that uses "Ticks" for a synchronized waiting in my main program.

   ```
   void WaitTicks(uint8_t TickCount) {
           Ticks = 0;

           while (Ticks < TickCount) {
   //                Ticks ++;
   //                 Ticks --;
           }
   }
   ```

This routine **is not linked** because the optimization will drop it.

The compiler "think" this routine cannot work because he ignores the increment of Ticks in the interrupt routine.

It will be only linked if i uncomment "Ticks ++;".
But then of course it will not wait for the interrupt increment.

So my code is not working and crashes at the point this 2. routine "WaitTicks" is called.
But it is compiled and linked without errors in every case.

My question is how can i cheat the compiler with this option in this special case?

I want to have the optimization, but it should work with this special interrupt problem also.

Comment: Yes - that's the solution! Thank you! Defining Ticks as volatile is working.

Answer (score 2):

`Ticks` needs to be volatile (or the compiler will assume that it cannot change during WaitTicks execution, since it is never written in that function. Thus your while loop would not perform any action, and can be dropped. As the whole function then does nothing, it is dropped, too). If it isn't a single byte variable (but I suppose it is, since TickCount is a uint8_t) you even need to read/write it atomically.

Comment: Of course this is the first correct answer. But i simply forgot to use volatile. So both of you give the correct "solution tip". ;-)